# Select elements with attribute value in a list of values

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

Having the following html elements

```
<div id="container">
    <div data-test="foo">foo</div>
    <div data-test="bar">bar</div>
    <div data-test="lol">lol</div>
    <div data-test="lorem">lorem</div>
    <div data-test="burger">burger</div>
</div>
```

I need to select all of those who have the `data-test` attribute value in a predefined set of values in order to change, for example, the background color. These values are stored in a pipe-separated-values string:

```
foo|lol|lorem|cartman
```

Based on this example, the expected result is to change the backgound color only to those divs having `data-test='foo'` OR `data-test='lol'` OR `data-test='lorem'` OR `data-test='cartman'`.

As the list of values may change in the future, I'd like to write a dynamic selector based on the string list provided above.

Right now I'm using the following code to build up the selector

```
var list = 'foo|lol|lorem|cartman';
var search = "[data-test='" + list.split("|").join("'],[data-test='") + "']";
$("#container").find(search).css("background", "red")
```

[***Find a fiddle here***](https://jsfiddle.net/hju5xbo8/)

Is there any jquery functionality that does the same work with less code or can you suggest a better approach to achieve the desired result?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
//Create an array
var list = 'foo|lol|lorem|cartman'.split('|'); 

//Filter elements
$("#container div[data-test]").filter(function(){
    //Test whether data exists in the list
    return list.indexOf($(this).data('test')) > -1;
}).css("background", "red")
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5g3yync/)